# How to run xterm in docker mininet

Tags: docker, mininet, xterm

I am new to docker. Inside of the docker, I opened mininet CLI and ran `xterm h1`, but got the error message `Error: Cannot connect to display`
[(msg picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNOZ.png) Is there anyone know how to fix this problem?

p.s. I found a page to solving this problem ([link](https://hub.docker.com/r/iwaseyusuke/mininet/)), but could not understand what is the "docker host" and where should I run `xhost +si:localuser:root`.

Comment: The `docker` host is the host on which the `docker` daemon process is running, that is where you should run `xhost +si:localuser:root` before `docker run`ning the container.

Comment: You need to jump through some (Linux-specific) hoops to get this to work; it's not a great match for Docker.  The linked question goes through the options and incantations.